# Javascript: DOM event not happening in setTimeout

Tags: javascript

So this my JS code

```
for (var i=0; i<500; i++) {
  var compare = cryptoSName[i].innerHTML
  if (compare == crypto) {
    document.getElementById("cryptotable" + i).style.color = "#00000"
    document.getElementById('price' + i).innerHTML= "$" + (tradeMsg.message.msg.price.toFixed(4));;
    document.getElementById('perc' + i).innerHTML= tradeMsg.message.msg.perc + "%";
    setTimeout(function() {
      document.getElementById("cryptotable" + i).style.color = "#ff0000"
    }, 500);
  }
}
```

when I run this, it throws an error saying that `cannot read property style of null`

Now, If I remove this, It works perfectly fine. **What am I doing wrong here?** Also, My goal here is to change the color of an element just for few seconds. How can I achieve that? (I was trying to do with setTimeout function)

Comment: also add html snippet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you're using `var`, `i` is hoisted: to the interpreter, your code actually looks something like this:

```
var i;
for (i=0; i<500; i++) {
  var compare = cryptoSName[i].innerHTML
  // ...
```

So at the end of your loop, `i` has a value of `500`, and you don't have an element with an ID of `...500`. Use `let` instead, since `let` has block scoping and isn't hoisted, unlike `var`:

```
for (let i = 0; i<500; i++) {
```